# Retrieve each row for a particular category

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have below query to list below records. But I want select only one record from each store from below list.

How to optimise below query to achieve this?

```
Select 
    o.StoreId,  
    o.OfferId,      
    OfferText       
From 
    Offers o 
Inner Join 
    (Select o1.StoreId
     From subcategorymap scm
     Inner Join Offers o1 On scm.OfferId = o1.OfferId   
     Where subcategoryid = 51
     Group By o1.StoreId
     Having Count(o1.StoreId) > 1) s1 On o.StoreId = s1.StoreId
```

I want to pull each one record for a store from below list.

```
StoreId OfferId OfferText
-------------------------
14      46      Great Deal
21      60      30% OFF
21      61      Rs.50 OFF
21      61      Rs.50 OFF
14      84      10% OFF
14      84      10% OFF
14      86      30% OFF
19      196     Rs.50 OFF
166     219     20% OFF
166     221     30% OFF
166     223     10% OFF
```

Output should be like:

```
StoreId OfferId OfferText
-------------------------
14      46      Great Deal
21      60      Rs.30 OFF
19      196     Rs.50 OFF
166     219     20% OFF
...     ...     ...
...     ...     ...
...     ...     ...
```

Comment: use group by and having caluses

Comment: or try distinct in `offer_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **distinct**

```
Select distinct 
    o.StoreId,  
    o.OfferId,      
    OfferText       
From 
    Offers o 
Inner Join 
    (Select o1.StoreId
     From subcategorymap scm
     Inner Join Offers o1 On scm.OfferId = o1.OfferId    
     Where  subcategoryid = 51
     Group By o1.StoreId
     Having Count(o1.StoreId) > 1) s1 On o.StoreId = s1.StoreId
```

Comment: It will only give 1 itme for store id 21 where as their should b 2

Comment: we can use distinct if entire row is duplicate but this is different case. please see my sample records above.

Answer (score 1):

Use Row_Number()

```
;With cte
As
(
Select 
RN = row_number() over(partition by o.storeid order by o.storeid,o.offerid),
    o.StoreId,  
    o.OfferId,      
    OfferText       
From 
    Offers o 
Inner Join 
    (Select o1.StoreId
     From subcategorymap scm
     Inner Join Offers o1 On scm.OfferId = o1.OfferId   
     Where subcategoryid = 51
     Group By o1.StoreId
     Having Count(o1.StoreId) > 1) s1 On o.StoreId = s1.StoreId
)
Select
*
From cte
Where RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MIN, such as:

```
Select 
    o.StoreId,  
    o.OfferId ,      
    OfferText       
From 
    Offers o 
Inner Join 
    (Select  o1.StoreId, MIN(o1.OfferId) OfferID
     From subcategorymap scm
     Inner Join Offers o1 On scm.OfferId = o1.OfferId   
     Where subcategoryid = 51
     Group By o1.StoreId
     Having Count(o1.StoreId) > 1) s1 On o.StoreId = s1.StoreId and  o.OfferID = s1.OfferID
```